# I want to use getElementsByName in my code

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyname

[This is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/k6ou0eos/):

```
 document.getElementsByName('submitButton').onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('valueA')[0].value),
      num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('valueB')[0].value),
      arithmeticOperator = document.getElementsByName('arithmeticOperator')[0].value,
      output = document.getElementsByName('result');

  switch(arithmeticOperator) {
    case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        if(num2 != 0)
        {
            result = num1 / num2;
        }else {
            result = 'Dela inte med 0!';
        }
        break;
    default:
        result = 'Error';
  }
  window.alert(result);
  return false;
};
```

My problem is that i can't get my code to generate a popup with the answer.
When I use ID in my html it works fine but I would like to learn how getElementsByName works instead. 
So, I don't want to change my HTML at all but I need help with my JS.

Comment: Do you have multiple submit buttons?

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName returns an array like object so you need to get the element by index and add the listener

```
document.getElementsByName('submitButton')[0].onclick = function(event) {
}
```

Note: In your page, I'm not able to see the button with the said name

---

Since you have a form, it is better to use the form's submit event

```
document.getElementById('calcForm').onsubmit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('valueA')[0].value) || 0,
        num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName('valueB')[0].value) || 0,
        arithmeticOperator = document.getElementsByName('arithmeticOperator')[0].value,
        output = document.getElementsByName('result');

    switch (arithmeticOperator) {
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            if (num2 != 0) {
                result = num1 / num2;
            } else {
                result = 'Cant devide bu 0';
            }
            break;
        default:
            result = 'Error';
    }
    document.getElementsByName('result')[0].innerHTML = result;
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p25h1n1r/)

Comment: This only registers an event handler for the first item, not sure that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: <form name="calcForm" id="calcForm">
  <p><input type="number" name="valueA" placeholder="Värde A" /></p>
  <p><input type="number" name="valueB" placeholder="Värde B" /></p>
  <select name="arithmeticOperator">
   <option value="+">Addition</option>
   <option value="-">Subtraktion</option>
   <option value="/">Division</option>
   <option value="*">Multiplication</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">GO</button>
  
  <p><output name="result" form="calcForm"></output></p>
 </form>

Comment: @cannondale there are no `submitButton` element in your html

Comment: @ArunPJohny can I use   break;
  default:
   result = 'Error';
 }
    window.alert(result);
    return false;
};

Comment: @cannondale did you try it... can you update the above fiddle to recreate your issue... the fiddle seems to be working